# set number format in html?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, string-formatting

I have a web application related vehicle record, in this application I want to add vehicle number. but client want fix format like box for it ->

```
RJ 19 NP 5020
```

please anybody help me for it.
thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything

Comment: A regex is OK . Try writing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
 ^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: hello Nikhil sir, can you give detail, how to use this ?

Comment: http://html5pattern.com/Make_Your_Own?pattern_new=MH-32%2CNY-1234#n=dcdd&p=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%5B%20%5C-%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5B%20%2C%5D%5BA-Z0-9%5D%7B2%2C3%7D%5B%20%5C-%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%24&d=For%20vehicle%20record&s=Source%E2%80%A6&pc[0]=%2B&nc[0]=-

Comment: you can write RJ 19 NP 5020 as RJ-19,NP-5020

Comment: sir can I set it in html input field like " RJ-19-NP-5020 " this format

Comment: yes just change above regex  to ^[A-Z]{2}[ \-][0-9]{2}[ -][A-Z0-9]{2,3}[ \-][0-9]{4}$

Comment: this is fine, I want in input field, user type in this way -> RJ-19-NP-5020

Comment: I think this will do it

Answer (score 1):

Use html pattern with regex like so:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([A-HJ-PR-Y]{2,2}[056][0-9]\s?[A-HJ-PR-Y]{3,3})$|^([A-HJ-NP-Y]{1,3}[0-9]{2,3}?\s[A-Z]{3,3})$|^([A-Z]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4}([A-Z]{1,1})?)$|^([0-9]{4,4}[A-Z]{1,3})$|^([A-Z]{1,2}\s?[0-9]{1,4})$|^([A-Z]{2,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4})$|^([0-9]{1,4}\s?[A-Z]{2,3})$">
```

I found this regex googling for UK number plate regex, and it seems to work OK for all the number plates (UK) i know.

see my fiddle for a test:
https://jsfiddle.net/7yh2wo12/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` HTML5 attribute where you can define regex for your string